# Equality in Lebesgue integration inequality

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ be a measure space and $\mu$ be a positive measure on it. Let $g:X\to \mathbb{C}$ be a complex valued $\mu-$integrable function. We know that
$$
\left| \int_X g d\mu \right| \leq \int_X |g| d \mu.
$$

I am trying to verify if the equality holds iff $g=|g|$, $\mu$-a.e. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality is true if and only if $g$ has constant phase, i.e.  if and only if there's a constant $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|=1$ such that $g=\alpha |g|$ almost everywhere.

To see that this condition is necessary, just go carefully through the proof that $|\int g|\leq \int |g|$ and see when equality can hold at each step.